# I am trying to create an alias to run an application. Is there away to bypass creating an alias just to change directories?

Tags: command-line, bash, alias

I am new to Linux and I want to create an alias to run an application.

Currently, to access it via the terminal I am typing:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
packettracer
```

Is there any way I can by pass creating an alias just to change directories? I just want to be able to type `pt` for example into the terminal and it instantly run, rather than typing two separate commands.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `echo $PATH` you should see `/usr/local/bin` is already in your path and there is no need to change to that directory in the first place. You can run the executable simply by typing `packettracer` - there is no need to `cd` to it.

Even if it is not in your PATH, you don't need to change to a program's / script's directory as a separate command; you can run it by prefixing the executable's name with the full path, in this case:

```
/usr/local/bin/packettracer
```

Therefore your alias can simply be:

```
alias pt='/usr/local/bin/packettracer'
```

or even

```
alias pt='packettracer'
```

Before setting an alias, check that the command you want to use doesn't already exist using the `type` command. Hopefully you will see that it is not in use:

```
$ type pt
bash: type: pt: not found
```

Once you have a suitable alias, to make is permanent you can add it to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file (use your favourite text editor; for example, open a terminal and type `nano .bashrc` add the alias, save and exit, and the alias will be available as soon as you open a new shell).